# Avoid duplicate name when importing a sub-module with only one public member from a package

Tags: python

### Basic Setup

Suppose I want to create a class named `Foo`. I may create a file like so:

**foo.py**:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = "world"
    def print(self):
        print("Hello, " + self.data)
```

To utilize this class in my main script:

**main.py**

```
import foo

test = foo.Foo()
test.print()
```

Having to type `foo.Foo()` every time I instantiate the class already feels ridiculous enough, but it gets worse when I want to organize my code by separating my classes into a package:

**classes/__init__.py**

```
# Empty
```

**classes/foo.py**

```
# Copy of foo.py, above
```

**main.py**

```
import classes.foo

test = classes.foo.Foo()
test.print()
```

### Simple Answer

I know I can clean this up somewhat by using `from X import Y` like so:

```
from classes.foo import Foo

test = Foo()
```

### Preferred Answer

Because the file `foo.py` contains ***only one*** member whose name matches the file, I would prefer if I could do something like the following:

```
from classes import Foo
# Or:
import classes.Foo as Foo

test = Foo()
```

Is there a way to do this? Maybe with some code in my `__init__.py`?

Comment: @martineau Updated the title. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `classes/__init__.py`, put:

```
from .foo import Foo
```

Now you can write `from classes import Foo`.